# Shouldn't importing print_function change the keyword.kwlist in python2?

Tags: python, python-2.x, keyword

In `python-2.7`, shouldn't the `keyword.kwlist` be updated after importing `print_function` from `__future__`?

```py
Python 2.7.18 (default, Feb  1 2021, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword('print')
True
>>> print = 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print = 3
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> 
>>> keyword.iskeyword('print')
True
>>> print = 3
>>> 
>>> print
3
>>> keyword.kwlist
['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

Is this kind of bug? Or it is intentional?

Comment: The contents of the `keyword` module is just a static list; there's no provision for changing it in response to a `__future__` import.  Perhaps this could be considered a bug - but with Python 2.7 being obsolete for so long, nobody is going to give the slightest thought towards actually fixing it.

Comment: @jasonharper Perfect explanation. Care making it into an answer? I would totally upvote it.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your comment. I'm really curious how Python can change it's keywords sets at runtime, does this mean it is changing rules of parsing the code at runtime? Would you provide any resource to learn more about how it works internally?

Comment: It's just a hard-coded special case in Parser/parser.c (around line 152) - if the keyword `print` is found, but the "print is a function" flag has been set, it breaks out of the loop that recognizes keywords, which allows it to be parsed as an ordinary identifier.